# Which directories are writeable in a system following FHS?

Tags: permissions, fhs

I need to ensure that, when deleting a specific user from a system, all of his/her files are removed. User creation/deletion will happen a lot on this system, so I want to reuse UID's and want to ensure the new user does not have access to any files of the old user.

My question is two-fold:

1. Is there a general and easy way to find all files owned by a specific user? Or is a system-wide `search -uid n` my only option?
2. If a system-wide search is the only option, then which directories are generally writeable by a normal user (suppose a distribution following [FHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard))?

   - His home directory
   - /tmp
   - ??

The user does not have `sudo` privileges, so he can only write in places that are world-writable in a standard Unix filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bit of research of my own. Main source: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/c23.html

Long story short: **there is nothing that prohibits a user from creating files**. However, in standard linux FHS, only some directories are writeable by everyone. As long as you use a distribution that follows this convention, you should only check the following directories (as shown by a test on my own system):

- /dev/shm (mounted by default in some distributions)
- User home directory
- /var/tmp
- /var/run/screen/S-rubenf
- /tmp
- /mnt/usb-disk (mounted with gid=users)

Source:

```
find -type d | 
  while read DIR; do 
    if touch $DIR/test_can_be_removed123 2>/dev/null; then 
      rm $DIR/test_can_be_removed123
      echo $DIR >> writable_directories
    fi
  done
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are removing an account, use `userdel -r`.  This removes the user's `home` directory together with its contents.  In addition the mail spool file belonging to the user is removed.

I wouldn't assume that any directory couldn't have held objects belonging to the user in question.  This is particularly true if the user had SUDO privileges.

Use `find` to look for the UID of the account that you are going to delete; or have just deleted:

```
find / -user <UID> -exec ls -ld {} +
```

where UID is replaced by the actual UID value in question, or the username if you haven't already deleted the account;

or, in general for UIDs that no longer map to any name:

```
find / -nouser -exec ls -ld {} +
```

These are portable among various Unix flavors (HP-UX, AIX, etc.) and among Linux distributions.  The GNU `find` allows the `-exec ls -ld {} +` to be replaced by `-ls`.

Comment: Note that `find -user` can take either a user name or a numeric user ID. See the man page.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Updated answer to reflect this.